# SSRS 2005 Issue with blank space between mulitiple tables when hiding and showing tables based on report critieria

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

I have been unable to find any information on the web, or any SSRS documentation to help me with this issue, you have worked through this problem before, I would greatly appeciate the assistance. I have a report that has about 8 tables from top to bottom of the layout. Based on the type of data queried, some tables should be displayed while others should not. Using the visibility settings to hide the table via an expression, while it hides the table it also leave a big blank space area between the tables where it was positioned on the report instead of the other tables rolling together as I would have expected.

Answer (score 0):

Move the table into a rectangle. That's it. Leave the Visibility expression on the table, and don't add it to the rectangle. The rectangle should "shrink up" when there is nothing to display inside of it.

Answer (score 0):

As per your layout i found that you have hidden that table but still it contains the design space so it showing some blank space. Please follow the below steps to resolve this issue.
1. Select one row of your table and go to visibility properties and select show and hide based on expression.
2. Repeat step-1 for all the rows.
3. Run and see the report output with out blank space.